# What's the best way to log xml data in spring boot?

Tags: xml, spring, logging, logback

My Spring Boot project use XML to communicate with Server. (RESTful API)

And I want to log pretty formatted xml data in my SpringBoot project(use logback for logging)

What's the best way to log pretty formatted xml in Spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something like this, I feel its good way. Change my `sysout` with your `log statement`.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class YourController{
.
.
.
.
    public yourRestMethod() {


        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setValidating(false);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = db.parse(new InputStream("Your XML")));
        prettyPrint(doc);

    }

    public static final void prettyPrint(Document xml) throws Exception {
        Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        Writer out = new StringWriter();
        tf.transform(new DOMSource(xml), new StreamResult(out));
        System.out.println(out.toString());
    }

}
```